# How to add click events to a 2D array of tiles objects in Java

Tags: java, actionlistener, tile

I am creating a 2D turn-based Star Wars game where the player has to move from tile to tile in a grid system, all the while avoiding enemies (I know, exciting stuff right!!). The grid is a 2D Array of Tiles, which are objects that I created using Slick and Light-Weight Java Game Library (lwjgl) so that I could add texture to them. I'm pretty new to all of this, and I'm trying to add click listeners to my tiles (or TileGrid?) so that when I click on a tile the player will move there, but I'm having no luck thus far. If any one could help in this matter they will receive my heartfelt thank you and 50% of the game rights when I sell the game to LucasArts!

Getters and Setters omitted

**Tile Class**

```
public class Tile {

  private float x, y, width, height;
  private Texture texture;
  private TileType type;

  public Tile(float x, float y, float width, float height, TileType type) {
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
    setWidth(width);
    setHeight(height);
    setType(type);
    setTexture(quickLoad(type.textureName));
  }

  public void draw() {
    drawQuadTex(texture, x, y, width, height);
  }
}
```

**TileGrid Class**

```
public class TileGrid extends JFrame {

  public Tile[][] map;

  public TileGrid() {
    int width = Artist.getGridWidth();
    int height = Artist.getGridHeight();
    map = new Tile[width][height];
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = new Tile(i * 64, j * 64, 64, 64, TileType.Space1);
        }
    }
  }

  public static int[][] randomGridGenerator() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int width = Artist.getGridWidth();
    int height = Artist.getGridHeight();
    int[][] map = new int[width][height];
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            int randInt = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
            map[i][j] = randInt;
        }
    }
    return map;
  }

  public TileGrid(int[][] newMap) {

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
        }
    });

    int width = Artist.getGridWidth();
    int height = Artist.getGridHeight();
    map = new Tile[width][height];
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            switch (newMap[i][j]) {
            case 1:
                map[i][j] = new Tile(i * 64, j * 64, 64, 64, TileType.Space1);
                break;
            case 2:
                map[i][j] = new Tile(i * 64, j * 64, 64, 64, TileType.Space2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
  }  

  public void setTile(int xCoord, int yCoord, TileType type) {
    map[xCoord][yCoord] = new Tile(xCoord * 64, yCoord * 64, 64, 64, type);
  }

  public Tile getRandomTile() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int width = Artist.getGridWidth();
    int height = Artist.getGridHeight();
    int x = rand.nextInt(width) ;
    int y = rand.nextInt(height);
    return map[x][y];
  }

  public Tile getTile(int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    return map[xCoord][yCoord];
  }

  public void draw() {
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            Tile t = map[i][j];
            drawQuadTex(t.getTexture(), t.getX(), t.getY(), t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());
        }
    }
```

}

**TileType Class**

```
public enum TileType {

    Space1("space64-1"), Space2("space64-2"), Space3("space64-3"), Space4("space64-4"), Space5("space64-5"),
    Space6("space64-6"), Space7("space64-7"), Space8("space64-8"), Space9("space64-9"), Space10("space64-10"),
    Space11("space64-11"), Space12("space64-12"), Space13("space64-13"), Space14("space64-14"), Space15("space64-15"),
    Space16("space64-16"), Space17("space64-17"), Space18("space64-18"), Space19("space64-19"), Space20("space64-20");

    String textureName;

    TileType(String textureName) {
        this.textureName = textureName;
    }

}
```

**Player Class**

```
public class Player extends SpaceShip {

    private TileGrid grid;
    private int width, height, health;
    float x, y;
    private Texture texture;
    private Tile locationTile;
    /*
    public Player(Texture texture, Tile startTile, int width, int height) {
        setTexture(texture);

        setX(startTile.getX());
        setY(startTile.getY());
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
    }
    */
    public Player(Texture texture, TileGrid grid, int width, int height) {
        setTexture(texture);
        Tile tile = grid.getRandomTile();
        setLocationTile(tile);
        setX(tile.getX());
        setY(tile.getY());
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
        setGrid(grid);
    }

    public void movePlayer() {
        int height = Artist.getHeight();
        Tile newLocation = grid.getTile((int) Math.floor(Mouse.getX() / 64), (int) Math.floor((height - Mouse.getY() - 1)/ 64));
        setLocationTile(newLocation);
        setX(newLocation.getX());
        setY(newLocation.getY());
    }

    public void draw() {
        drawQuadTex(texture, x, y, width, height);
    }
```

**Entry Point**

```
public class Boot {

    public Boot() {

        beginSession();
        int[][] map = randomGridGenerator();
        TileGrid grid = new TileGrid(map);
        // Player p = new Player(quickLoad("x-wing"), grid.getTile(10, 10), 64, 64);
        Player p = new Player(quickLoad("x-wing"), grid, 64, 64);
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            grid.draw();
            p.draw();
            //p.movePlayer();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Boot();
    }

}
```

}

**Artist Class (for rendering etc.)**

```
public class Artist {

    public static final int WIDTH = 1280, HEIGHT = 960;
    public static final int GRID_WIDTH = 20, GRID_HEIGHT = 15;

    public static void beginSession() {
        Display.setTitle("Star Wars");
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    public static void drawQuad(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x + width, y);
        glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
        glVertex2f(x, y + height);
        glEnd();
    }

    public static void drawQuadTex(Texture tex, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        tex.bind();
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(width, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(width, height);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, height);
        glEnd();
        glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public static Texture loadTexture(String path, String fileType) {
        Texture tex = null;
        InputStream in = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
        try {
            tex = TextureLoader.getTexture(fileType, in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tex;
    }

    public static Texture quickLoad(String name) {
        Texture tex = null;
        tex = loadTexture("resources/" + name + ".png", "PNG");
        return tex;
    }
```

In my attempt above the event should just return the coordinates when I click on it. My intention is to complete the player move logic once I've set up the event listener. All help appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the output from your `mouseClicked()` method when clicking on the content of the Tilegrid?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. No, nothing appears in the console.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code as a [mcve]. Keep in mind that you have two constructors for `TileGrid`, one without any arguments and one with an arrays as an argument. However you add the mouse listener only in one of the constructors. You might need to move your code around, maybe even use `this()` in the constructor with the array argument, to make sure that the mouse listener is always added, regardless if you use `new TileGrid()` or `new TileGrid(array);`.

Comment: Code updated. I've omitted the getters and setters for clarity.

Comment: It looks like you are using OpenGL for displaying the application. When you use such a library (I guess lwglj?), why do you have `TileGrid` extend from `JFrame` when you are not using the Swing library at all?

Comment: You might want to look at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24689/detecting-a-click-on-a-tile

Comment: I get error message on addMouseLIstener() when I don't extend JFrame, so I assumed they're linked somehow. Couldn't find another way around it.